# Calling a command from external software using Popen() function

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am writing a Python script and I have to call a command from an external software. I am currently using the Popen() function to call such a command. The command has some options too. I want to know how to incorporate these options into the Popen() function. The code I am using now is:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
proc = Popen(["halSummarizeMutations", hal_output], stdout=PIPE)
summary_mutation = proc.communicate()[0]
```

In the Popen() function, I am supposed to take in a variable for an option of the command. The modified code should look like:

```
proc = Popen(["halSummarizeMutations", --option optioninput, hal_output], stdout=PIPE)
```

Is the code right or is there a different method to code it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you try subprocess to open external program? http://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/

Comment: What are the contents of the variable `hal_output`? In any case, `--option optioninput` will need to be a string.

Comment: @Kevin hal_ouput is one variable and that is not the problem I am having. The problem is with the other variable I want to accept, optioninput for the specific option...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want add some parameter to the external software, just add the variables as a string, here is an example of "ls -la", you can add "-la" to the list, you can add any 
other parameters to the list.Remember the parameters are all string.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
proc = Popen(["ls", '-la'], stdout=PIPE) # if you want more, add after "-la"
print proc.stdout.readlines()
```

Comment: downvote. Why would you use `p.stdout.readlines()` if even the question code uses `p.communicate()[0]` here?

Answer (score 1):

Provide each argument as a separate list item:

```
from subprocess import check_output

cmd = ["halSummarizeMutations", "--option", "optioninput", hal_output]
summary_mutation = check_output(cmd)
```

where `hal_output` is a string variable defined earlier.